# Some wing parts designation

Tags: wing

[image: Trailind edge]
Under the trailing edge, there are 3 features, as seen in the picture. What's the name and the purpose of them?
The chord line is the distance between the leading and trailing edge.
What's the name of the upper and the lower surface of a wing?

Comment: @Steve He is asking for a little more than just that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The three bodies are the housings for the flap actuators and they do just that. There is no special name for the upper and lower wing surfaces that I know of or can find, just "upper" and "lower".

Answer (score 3):

The sharp pods are called anti-shock bodies or flap track fairings. See [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/7955/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-sharp-pods-under-airliner-wings) for further information. Simply put, htey are there to reduce drag- transonic drag by smoothly varying the cross sectional area (Whitcomb Area rule) and by covering the flap actuators.

The straight line connecting the wing leading and trailing edges is called chord line; the distance between them is called chord length (both are usually called chord).

The upper and lower wing sufraces are called, well, upper surface and lower surface of wing.